# Extracting multiple excel files as Pandas data frame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-extraction, data-ingestion

I'm trying to create a data ingestion routine to load data from multiple excel files with multiple tabs and columns in the pandas data frame. The structuring of the tabs in each of the excel files is the same. Any help would be appreciated!!

```
folder = "specified_path"
files = os.listdir(folder)
sheet_contents = {}

for file in files:
    data = pd.ExcelFile(folder+file)
    file_data = {}

    for sheet in data.sheet_names:
        file_data[sheet] = data.parse(sheet)

    sheet_contents[file[:-5]] = file_data
```

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: So, I have successfully tried extracting data in the dictionary data structure. But, now I want to do the same for pandas data frames. Attaching the code in question.

Comment: And what is your expected output exactly ? A single dataframe that holds all the sheets (tabs) from all the excel files ?

Comment: So, earlier I expected to have a dictionary with file names as keys and values as the excel files and another nested dictionary with tabs as keys and columns of tabs as values. But now I'm trying to create a data structure of all the excel files as a pandas data frame. Not a single df, but each one should have its own data frame separately in one data structure (maybe list). Data cannot be merged in one data frame from all the excel files. Is that possible??

Comment: If I understand correctly, for example, for a folder that contains 3 Excel files (with 10 sheets/tabs each), we need to have as a final output : 3 dataframes. Is that it ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But, can we put all those data frames in one single data structure?

Comment: I posted an answer. Let me know if it correponds to your excpected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to create a dataframe for each excelfile (stored in a specific folder and that holds multiple sheets) is by using [**`pandas.read_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) combined. By passing the parameter `sheet_name=None` to [**`pandas.read_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), we can read in all the sheets in the excelfile at one time.

Try this :

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder = 'specified_path'

excel_files = [file for file in os.listdir(folder)]

list_of_dfs = []
for file in excel_files :
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(folder + "\\" + file, sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
    df['excelfile_name'] = file.split('.')[0]
    list_of_dfs.append(df)
```

To access to one of the dataframes created, you can use its index (e.g, `list_of_dfs[0]`) :

```
print(type(list_of_dfs[0]))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works fine as of now. I'll recheck the requirements and get back if there is any issue.

Comment: Can you please let me know what (df['excelfile_name'] = file.split('.')[0]) is doing in the code?

Comment: Also, there is a new development that data in each sheet should not be concatenated. Each sheet should be a different dataframe, is that possible??